# Are there English language books that show the difference between words with similar meanings?

Tags: synonyms

I'm going to learn use words with meaning near each other in correct way.
For example “session” and “meeting” may look like each other but their meaning differ slightly.

Are there any books/type of books which shows how to use them in correct way (for me who wants to learn English as 2nd language)?

Comment: Some dictionaries include information of that nature for some words.

Comment: This is a hard way to learn. You need to see the words in context to understand differences and register, and you get this from reading, not from definitions.

Comment: Typing _word1 word2 difference_ into Google can be informative, but ignore Wikidiff which seems to be generated by a robot. Search results that point to discussions on web sites (this site and its sister, English Language Learners often appear) can be useful.

Comment: Books of English Usage normally cover this to some extent (although a lot of them are written by pedants/eccentrics rather than based on actual usage), and if you search Amazon there are loads of books called things like Confused Words which I've not read and can't recommend. If you're worried about a particular word, you'd be better off googling, as already mentioned.

Comment: You need a good *dictionary* and you need a good *thesaurus*.  That'll learn you the basics.  Beyond that, and most of English usage is beyond that, you need a large corpus of native written and spoken English within which to search for usages of the words you might be interested in.  Oh, and a good search engine.

Comment: Safire's 'The Right Word in the Right Place at the Right Time' is a good read. But Xanne is right; there is no substitute for general reading of quality books. And nnnnnn points out that some dictionaries nowadays strive to show when synonyms are not interchangeable. But they'd have to be enormous to be comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

While a good dictionary and a good thesaurus are excellent references, you will find that the context in which a word is used can vary its meaning. So there aren't necessarily any differences between words that will **always** hold true.

The more you read, the more examples you will see of how words and phrases are used. Above all, this will likely improve your understanding of English language usage. Much of what's characterized as "artificial intelligence" today is really "machine learning" where you show the computer as many examples as possible of a correct answer so it can learn to distinguish those from other uses. That's essentially what reading does for us. We don't read at the speed of a computer, but we learn similarly.